# VScode Jupyter cannot connect to my venv python3 kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VScode to run my ipynb files. The python extension auto-upgraded today and then the jupyter files cannot connect to my python3 venv. I can only solve this problem by degrading the extension version to the one released 1 month ago.

I'm using the setting.json file to declare the path of kernel

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": " /Users/xuehuisun/fca3/bin/python3"
}
```

These are available options for jupyter kernel BEFORE the degrading:

[image]

These are available options for jupyter kernel AFTER the degrading:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the pictures of the python interpreter selection list under the different python extension versions? And the "python.defaultInterpreterPath" has instead of "python.pythonPath".